# CefSharp.WinForms Error (GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-532462766)

Tags: cefsharp

I'm getting CefSharp setup for the first time. I've installed the NuGet CefSharp.WinForms version 99.2.90. I've ran it in both build x64 and x86. x64 threw a DLL error which shows me it should be built in x86.
I've tried quite a few different methods I've found online but simply starting CefSharp throws an error.

running chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com"); results in the below error:

```
[0315/133306.821:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-532462766
[0315/133306.821:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
[0315/133306.821:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(447)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
The program '[18264] CefSharp.exe' has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f).
```

Form Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using CefSharp.DevTools.IO;

namespace TemarkNamespace
{

    public partial class CefSharpController : Form
    {

        private ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

        public CefSharpController()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
        }


        private void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Event Viewer error:

```
Application: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
   at CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: Try running the minimum example and confirm it works as expected. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: I think this is my issue:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/bf88e9ff6ed535334692de502a32cb5b0924102b
Just need to figure out what that is telling me to do.

But this is for offscreen example. Not Windows Forms. Still looking into this.

Comment: You need to add an app.manifest to your application as per the instructions https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/99/NuGet/Readme.txt#L13 The WinForms example also has an app.manifest

Comment: If you are still having problems then please confirm the,minimum example works as expected

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I missed the instuctions on https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/99/NuGet/Readme.txt#L13
My issue is resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed the instructions https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/99/NuGet/Readme.txt#L13
I created the app.manifest file and it worked great. Thanks for the help amaitland!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue When Sophos Endpoint protection was present on the system (Windows 10), and the Application Control was enabled. I the Events we could see that CEFLib was disabled. Took a while we figured out...[image]