# Unable to disable GPU in CefSharp settings

Tags: cefsharp

CefSharp v99.2.120
I am getting the following error in my CefSharp application:
`ERROR::gpu_process_host.cc (967) GPU process exited unexpetedly: exit_code=532462766 WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1273) The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)` 
And this repeats until crashed 3 times until
`FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(417) GPU process isn't usable.  Goodbye/`

I am using the following settings:
`CefSettings settings = new CefSettings() settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu");`

`settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing");`

`settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync");`

`settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-software-rasterizer");`

App still crashes with same error.
Added

`settings.DisableGpuAcceleration()`

Still the same.

Expected there to be no GPU in use, but using the above settings doesn't alter anything.

Comment: Did you add an app.manifest to your application? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71487359/cefsharp-winforms-error-gpu-process-exited-unexpectedly-exit-code-532462766